# Detecting State changes made by Bluetooth adapter through a background service

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have been trying to develop a service that detects BLE devices in the background. The background service runs seemlesly when bluetooth is enabled. However when bluetooth is not running i turn on bluetooth via

```
bluetoothAdapter.enable();
```

In order to listen to changes made by the bluetooth adapter i declare a broadcastreceiver in my service in the onCreate() method like this:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

My broadcast receiver looks like this:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() 
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.v("Broadcast called", "in service");
        if (action.equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)) 
        {
            final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);
            switch (state) {
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF:
                Log.v("Bluetooth state", "Off");
                break;
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF:
                Log.v("Bluetooth state", "Turning Off");
                break;
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
                Log.v("Bluetooth state", "Turned On");
                scanLeDevice(true) ;
                break;
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON:
                Log.v("Bluetooth state", "Turning On");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

the adapter.enable() call turns bluetooth on successfully however the problem i am facing here is that the onReceive method in the receiver never gets triggered as a result of which i cannot run and scan for BLE devices.

When i do these exact same steps in an activity everything works perfectly.

At first i thought that the onReceive is not triggered because the service is in a background thread. So i also triggered the service via a WakefullBroadcastReceiver but that made no change in behavior.

I would like to understand what i am doing wrong here and some help in solving this.